# Django button in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On user form view, add button "Login As", that button will execute functionality that we login as that user. Only admins can see/execute this functionality.
This is my question, how this to make?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these [packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/user-switching/) would be of use to you.